# The nth-child selectors do not work with Tingle.js' classes that belong to JavaScript on mobile phones

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

- The class `tingle-modal__close` does not exist in HTML because it belongs to JavaScript. JavaScript will add this class when you click the hyperlink anchor to open the modal.
- The class `tingle-modal__close` do exists in Tinge CSS file. But the `nth-child` selector does not work with that class because that class belongs to JavaScript. Here is the small example:

```
  .tingle-modal__close:nth-child(1) 
  {
    background-color: var(--orange-600) !important;
  }

  .tingle-modal__close:nth-child(2) 
  {
    background-color: var(--purple-600) !important;
  }
```

It means the first window close button is orange and the second is purple.

With clicked/enabled/open modal, the compiled HTML, with `tingle-modal__close` added by JavaScript:

```
<div class="tingle-modal tingle-modal--visible" style="">
  <button type="button" class="tingle-modal__close">
    <span class="tingle-modal__closeIcon">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M.3 9.7c.2.2.4.3.7.3.3 0 .5-.1.7-.3L5 6.4l3.3 3.3c.2.2.5.3.7.3.2 0 .5-.1.7-.3.4-.4.4-1 0-1.4L6.4 5l3.3-3.3c.4-.4.4-1 0-1.4-.4-.4-1-.4-1.4 0L5 3.6 1.7.3C1.3-.1.7-.1.3.3c-.4.4-.4 1 0 1.4L3.6 5 .3 8.3c-.4.4-.4 1 0 1.4z" fill="#000" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
      </svg>
    </span>
    <span class="tingle-modal__closeLabel">Close</span>
  </button>
    <div class="tingle-modal-box">
        <div class="tingle-modal-box__content">
            <h1>Section 1</h1>
            <blockquote>“I'm selfish, impatient and a little insecure. I make mistakes, I am out of control and at times hard to handle. But if you can't handle me at my worst, then you sure as hell don't deserve me at my best.”</blockquote>
            <cite>Marilyn Monroe</cite>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can test with JSFiddle and please resize preview window to less than 530px:
https://jsfiddle.net/gusbemacbe/k8v74gwb/1/

Comment: `:nth-child`, as its name kind of suggests, is the Nth child of its parent. When you open the modal, the close button is always the first child of the modal. Using something like `.tingle-modal:nth-child(1) .tingle-modal__close` would be more fitting, if the modals are always in the right order ([does not seem to be the case](https://jsfiddle.net/d60f4jz8/))

Comment: @blex, is there solution to fix it? It seems related to Robin's CSS or JavaScript issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:nth-child`, as its name kind of suggests, is the Nth child of its parent. When you open the modal, the close button is always the first child of the modal. Using something like `.tingle-modal:nth-child(1) .tingle-modal__close` would be more fitting, if the modals are always in the right order ([does not seem to be the case, they're reversed](https://jsfiddle.net/d60f4jz8/))

But the [Tingle.js](https://tingle.robinparisi.com/) library allows you to provide a `cssClass` option, if you want to add classes to the modal. You can use this to do what you want:

https://jsfiddle.net/d60f4jz8/2/

JS

```
var modalTinyNoFooter = new tingle.modal({
        cssClass: ['modal-1'],
        // ...
    });
// ...
var modalTinyNoFooter2 = new tingle.modal({
        cssClass: ['modal-2'],
        // ...
    });
// ...
var modalTinyNoFooter3 = new tingle.modal({
        cssClass: ['modal-3'],
        // ...
    });
// ...
```

CSS

```
.tingle-modal.modal-1 .tingle-modal__close {
  background-color: var(--orange-600) !important;
}

.tingle-modal.modal-2 .tingle-modal__close {
  background-color: var(--purple-600) !important;
}
```